# How to create excel/xlsx report from wizard in odoo 14

Tags: python, report, odoo, xlsx, odoo-14

how to generate xlsx report from wizard in odoo 14.
I have made a button in wizard

in wizard.py

```
 classReceivedReportWizard(models.TransientModel):
        _name = 'po.goods.report.wizard'

  

        def print_xls(self):
            context = self._context
            data = {
            'ids': self.ids,
            'model': self._name,}

        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.report',
            'data': {'model': 'po.goods.report.wizard',
                     'options': json.dumps(data, default=date_utils.json_default),
                     'output_format': 'xlsx',
                     'report_name': 'product receiving statement',
                     },
            'report_type': 'xlsx'
        }
```

in xml

```
<record id="goods_received_details_xlsx" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">product receiving report</field>
        <field name="model">po.goods.report.wizard</field>
        <field name="report_name">goods_received_report.report_goods_received_xlsx</field>
    </record>
```

in report.py

```
_name = 'report.goods_received_report.report_goods_received_xlsx'
    _inherit = 'report.report_xlsx.abstract'


    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, vendors):
        format0 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 14, 'align': 'vcenter', 'bold': True})
        format1 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 11, 'align': 'vcenter', 'bold': True})
        format2 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 8, 'align': 'vcenter', })
        sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Student Data Card')
        sheet.write(2, 4, 'test Details', format0)
```

please suggest how to get excel report in odoo14

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `print_xls` in wizard view xml?

```
<button name="print_xlx"/>
```

I don't understand why you declared qweb-pdf in xml when you wanted to print xlsx. To print xlsx, you need to install a new module for xlsx reporting.

Comment: yes.I have called "print_xls" button from wizard.xml